# control access to a folder using .htaccess - only if using particular domain

Tags: .htaccess, permissions

i have 2 domains pointing to the same site - say a.com and b.com - i have a folder /admin on the site, that i only want to be accessible by people who access using b.com, so b.com/admin would work but a.com/admin would give an access error.

Can this be done through htaccess?

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

```
order deny,allow
deny from all
allow from 192.168.0.0/24
```

from http://corz.org/serv/tricks/htaccess.php

i havent tested this but the way he describes it on the website thats what it does.

Otherwise just go with htpasswd.

Comment: hi there, this isn't what i'm looking for. i'm not looking to restrict access by client ip/domain.

Comment: instead of ip you can put the url in there i think

Comment: not issue of ip or url. this is not what i am looking for at all.

Answer (score 0):

Use a RewriteCond to check for the current domain, like so:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}  ^a.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^admin/ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/ [R,NC,L]
```

This will redirect requests from a.com to the root of the site. Requests from b.com can access admin/ just fine.

(from the same site linked-to by slex)